# Looking for Pivot Chart capability similar to Excel's PivotChart

Tags: .net, pivot, charts

I am looking for a .NET pivot charting component that is similar to Excel's PivotChart. This component would be used to display data to users as part of a smart client. Users may wish to slice and dice the data in a variety of ways. Ideally, the PivotChart component would allow the user to select a variety of ways to group and aggregate data.

I already have the capability to export the data to Excel; however, I would prefer to keep the PivotChart reporting capability directly inside my application for security reasons (watermarking, etc.) and for simplicity.

I have experimented briefly with wrapping the System.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Chart with a UI similar to the one in Excel but decided I shouldn't re-invent the wheel if there are already existing solutions.

I have done a survey and found many solutions that involve add-ins to Excel, but as explained above an ideal solution would not have any dependency on Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time browsing I discovered that there is no generic PivotChart component for either WinForms or WPF.

I was able to implement said capability using the System.WIndows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Chart and adding an options pane where users could select which fields would be used to plot the X and Y values, which methods would be used to aggregate data, and which fields would be used to group values into series.

I can't post a link to the solution because it is owned by my company, but just wanted to report that in this there is no 3rd party component to leverage.